# Decreasing function that behaves like $1-x^2$ for small $x$ and like $e^{-x}$ for large $x$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, asymptotics

I am trying to find a function with a domain $D = \mathbb{R}_+$, that is behaving like $1-x^2$ for small $x$ and like $e^{-x}$ for large $x$.

**Edit:** *And is monotonically decreasing.*

I thought about using $\chi^2$-distribution or a combination of logistic functions with adding a symmetric "normal density function like".

I would be glad if someone could help me. Or is there a general method how one approach such problems.

Comment: Out of curiosity (the question is interesting by itself, but is there a motivation for the specifics of the asymptotics you seek? (Additional comment: you may want to throw in that $f$ is required smooth or at least $C^1$, otherwise the function equal to $1-x^2$ on $[0,x_0]$ and equal to $e^{-x}$ on $(x_0,\infty)$, where $x_0 \approx 0.714$ is the positive solution to $e^{-x} = 1-x^2$, would trivially do...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way: let

$$f(x)= e^{-g(x)}$$

for some $g(x)$ such that $g(x) \sim x $ as $x\to \infty$ and $g(x) \sim x^2$ as $x \to 0$. For example we can take

$$g(x)=\frac{x^2}{x+1}$$

or, perhaps more elegant (and even), $g(x)= \sqrt{x^2+1/4}-1/2$, which gives:

$$ f(x) = \exp\left( \frac{1-\sqrt{4{{x}^{2}}+1}}{2}\right) $$

with $f(x) = 1 - x^2 + O(x^4)$ around $x=0$

[image]

Comment: Very nice. ${}$

Comment: Awesome! You guys are incredible.

Answer (score 7):

Let us consider a function $f\colon\mathbb{R}_+\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$
f(x) = \frac{1+ax+x^2}{1+bx+x^2}e^{-x}
$$
for $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ to be chosen. We do have the right asymptotics when $x\to\infty$, namely $f(x) \displaystyle\operatorname*{\sim}_{x\to\infty} e^{-x}$ *(that was the point of choosing this particular form for $f$)*. Now, let us pick $a,b$ such that
$$
f(x) \operatorname*{=}_{x\to0^+} 1-x^2 + o(x^2)
$$

Doing a Taylor expansion of $f$ at $0$:
$$
f(x) = 1 + (a - b - 1) x + \left( \frac{1}{2} - a + b - a b + b^2\right) x^2 + o(x^2)
$$

we find that we must have $a-b=1$ and $b+b^2-a (b+1)=-\frac{3}{2}$ for the coefficients of $x$ to cancel and that of $x^2$ to be $1$. [Solving](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+%7Ba-b%3D1,+b%2Bb%5E2-a+(b%2B1)+%3D+1%7D), we obtain
$$
a = \frac32,\quad b = \frac12
$$
that is
$$
f(x) = \frac{1+\frac{3}{2}x+x^2}{1+\frac{1}{2}x+x^2}e^{-x}
= \frac{2+3x+2x^2}{2+x+2x^2}e^{-x}
$$

*PS: as a bonus, since the denominator never cancels we have that $f$ is actually defined on $\mathbb{R}$, not only $\mathbb{R}_+$; and the function **is** monotonically decreasing on $(0,\infty)$. (Although, to be honest I was not aiming for that at first, and saw the OP's edit afterwards.)*

[image]

Comment: Remark: proving the monotonicity involves (unless there is a more elegant way) differentiating and solving... this is a bit ugly, but doable.

Comment: Thank you alot! I knew there was something relatively simple :).

Comment: My pleasure! If I may, what is the original motivation for your question? (Besides the self-sufficient interest of solving it for its own sake.)

Comment: We try to find a function as initial condition, which has these properties. Our supervisor told to find such function. Actually I am not quite sure why he wants this specific behaviour. BTW the self-sufficient interest got bigger with the time we spent on the problem :D.

Comment: @MrYouMath Agreed -- the intermediary question often end up overshadowing the goal.

Answer (score 3):

$$e^{-x^2}(1-x^2)+\frac{x^3}{x^3+1}e^{-x}$$

Comment: Not the right behavior at $0$, it goes like $1-x+o(x)$. Consider $$e^{-x^2}(1-x^2)+\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}e^{-x}$$ instead?

Comment: Ah, thanks @ClementC., that can be fixed easily.

Comment: @ClementC. your second term will include more than wanted for small x at the $x^2$ level.

Comment: Nope, it will not: it will be $1-x^2 +o(x^2)$ [as wanted](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series+e%5E(-x%5E2)(1-x%5E2)+%2B+(x%5E(2)%2F(1%2Bx%5E(2)))+e%5E(-x)+at+0) (and has the very small advantage of being defined on $\mathbb{R}$). (but +1)

Comment: Thank you alot. But this function has a hump in the middle? Is it possible to construct somethig momotonic decreasing?

Comment: Thank you alot your post allows to construct a whole class of functions with desired behaviour :).

Answer (score 1):

Following a comment made above, below the OP's question:

One may want to throw in the question that $f$ is required smooth or at least $C^1$ (note that the [function from my other answer is indeed smooth](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1809885/75808)), otherwise the following continuous non-increasing function $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ does — trivially — the job:
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
1-x^2 & 0 \leq x < x_0\\
e^{-x} & x > x_0\\
1 & x < 0
\end{cases}
$$
where $x_0\simeq 0.714$ is the only positive solution to the equation $e^{-x} = 1-x^2$.

[image]

Comment: +1: Thank you, but I need something smooth :)